# Uncaught SoapFault

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am getting the following error when trying to create a new SoapClient.

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx?wsdl" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\Ice\default\soaptest.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\Ice\default\soaptest.php(8): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://api.min...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\Ice\default\soaptest.php on line 8

what would cause the WSDL to not load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable openssl in your **php.ini** you load the WSDL over **https** this is only working when the openssl module is enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this might be the case with you but if you are using the PHP classes provided on the Minbody API on Github, note that they have recently updated them. I had the same problem with classService.php. If you are using classService.php, update the constructor function to the following (same will apply to other services):

```
function __construct($debug = false)
{
    $endpointUrl = "https://" . GetApiHostname() . "/0_5/ClassService.asmx";
    $wsdlUrl = $endpointUrl . "?wsdl";

    $this->debug = $debug;
    $option = array();
    if ($debug)
        {
            $option = array('trace'=>1);
        }
    $this->client = new soapclient($wsdlUrl, $option);
    $this->client->__setLocation($endpointUrl);
}
```